# Prove that if A has imaginary eigenvalues and the flows $e^{tA}$ and $e^{tB}$ are topologically conjugate, then B has the same imaginary eigenvalues.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Show that if A has eigenvalues of the form $\pm i \beta$, with $\beta \neq 0$ and the flows $e^{tA}$ and $e^{tB}$ are topologically conjugate, then $\pm i \beta$ also are eigenvalues of $B$.

**Definitions:**

$(i)$ Let $(f^t)_t$ and $(g^t)_t$ be flows of the following autonomous differential equations $x' = F(x)$, $F: \mathcal{U} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ and $y' = G(y), G: \mathcal{V} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, with $F$ and $G$ continuous funtions defined over open sets. The flows $(f^t)_t$ and $(g^t)_t$ are said to be **topologically conjugate** if there exists a homeomorphism $h: \mathcal{U} \longrightarrow \mathcal{V}$ such that $f^t(x)$ is defined if and only if $g^t(h(x))$ is defined. In such case, $h(f^t(x)) = g^t(h(x))$.

$(ii)$ Two flows $(f^t)_t$ and $(g^t)_t$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ are said to be **linearly conjugate** if there exists a linear isomorphism $h: \mathbb{R}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $h \circ f^t = g^t \circ h,$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt:** My initial idea was to exhibit a linear isomorphism that conjugates $e^{tA}$ and $e^{tB}$, because we know that such flows are linearly conjugate if and only if $A$ and $B$ are similar, therefore have the same eigenvalues. I also tried to prove that such flows are $C^1$-conjugate, but did not succeed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The smallest nontrivial subspaces contained in generalized eigenspaces give rise to periodic orbits.